# How to make Drop down box values as link

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to list products in ascending and descending order by price.I have these 2 values in drop down list.So when i select ascending from drop box, i want to use it as `@requestmapping` value in controller.How can i do it in jsp and spring.Please suggest me.

Comment: Ok, so you have a list of products. And somewhere near this list you have a select menu with "Sort Ascending" and "Sort Descending" values in them. And if a user chooses "Sort Ascending", you want that to make a request to your server and to be handled by a particular HandlerMethod. Yes?

Comment: You need to attach JavaScript to the drop-down's change event that causes the form to submit with a value to indicate to the backend to sort according to the selection.

Comment: @Neil yes that is what i meant. Could you tell how i could do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have your product list HTML setup already.

Your menu should look something like this:

```
<form method="GET">
    <select name="sort" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="Price,ASC">Ascending</option>
        <option value="Price,DESC">Descending</option>
    </select>
    <button>Go</button>
</form>
```

When the user selects an item in the menu or clicks the button it will submit the form with the URL like http://example.com/product-list?sort=Price,ASC [or DESC]

Your server would then need to grab those parameters, sort the output and return the output.

I used that particular URL format as it's compatible with Spring Data JPA.